# Why i cannot open file programmatically after saving it with File.WriteAllBytes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a base64 string image, what i did is; i converted the string into an array of bytes, and saved the file. Then, i tries to access the file for bitmap purposes but the system throws an exception: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. I am using File.WriteAllBytes which is mainly a synchronous function.

```cs
Byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(baseString);
File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, bytes);
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.FromFile(filePath) as Bitmap;
```

I expect to open the file without facing any problem since WriteAllBytes method is synchronous

Comment: `WriteAllBytes` closes the file after writing, so your problem might lie somewhere else. Do you write to the file anywhere else in the code?

Comment: Your code works just fine for me.

Comment: I would also think using Bitmap.FromStream with a MemoryStream would be better than hitting the filesystem.

Comment: What **exact** exception is thrown, and by which **exact** line of code?

Answer (score 1):

> Why i cannot open file programmatically after saving it with File.WriteAllBytes

If you get "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" and you know you don't have any open file handles, then the culprit is typically an Antivirus program.  Could also be something like a backup or file sync service, but less likely.